# Less absorption in Minimal Logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I just wonder whether the following is not derivable in [Minimal Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_logic):

$$ \bot \dashv\vdash \bot \land A  \hspace{3em}\mbox{/* not derivable */   }$$

I read this that although Minimal Logic attaches some meaning to the 
symbol $\bot$, it does not attach enough meaning as for the above law to hold.

Comment: You're using $f$ to represent falsehood, typically denoted $\bot$, right?  Otherwise I don't see what other symbol would have a special meaning associated with it.

Comment: Now the comment /* not derivable */ is gone, and it looks as I state something true. Can this comment be restored in math?

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it would still be covered by "I wonder whether the following is derivable?", but I'll put a comment back in.

Comment: This is a kind of a tex challenge for me.

Comment: No worries, there's always a learning curve with $\TeX$.  If you see interesting questions or answers, click edit to see the source and make note of what the writers did; learning by example is a great way to learn!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reading is correct.  Minimal logic, as discussed in the wikipedia article that you linked to, rejects the principle that everything follows from $\bot$.  One direction of that provability claim *does* hold.  It is true that:

$$ \bot \land A \vdash \bot \tag{1}$$

simply by the laws of conjunction (which would have for any formulae $\phi$ and $\psi$ that $\phi \land \psi \vdash \phi$).  It is the other direction that does not hold.  As the article mentioned, entailments of the form

$$ \bot \vdash A \tag{2}$$

do not hold, in general, in minimal logic.  However, entailments of the form

$$ \bot \vdash \lnot A \tag{3}$$

do hold.  As a result, it does hold that

$$ \bot \dashv\vdash \bot \land \lnot A \tag{4}$$

Comment: So you assume inversion for conjunction, i.e. if A |- B /\ C, then A |- B and A |- C? To make the argument go through?

Comment: Since $B \land C \vdash B$, I'm comfortable asserting that _if_ $A \vdash B \land C$, then $A \vdash B$.  That is, $\vdash$ should be transitive.

Comment: Yes, sounds good!